# StopSelf does not stop my service

Tags: android, service

Googling around, I have seen this problem posted many times, some of the posts on this forum over that last few years.  I have never seen anyone get a straight answer.

I have a foreground service that tries to stop itself after running for 2 hours by doing a this.StopSelf().  I've tried it when it's bound and when it's unbound.  On the AVD and on a device.

It simply does not work.  Is this a bug in Android? (running 2.3.3).

How can a service stop itself?

Comment: Have you tried `stopSelf()`

Comment: Huh???  That's what I'm using: stopSelf(). It doesn't stop the service.

Comment: You weren't being clear. You used both stopService() and stopSelf() in your question. Does making the Service background (calling stopForeground()) then stopping the service work?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean stopSelf.  Played around with stopForeground() and it makes stopSelf() work eventually.  Seems  to take several seconds to work.

Comment: When you say **foreground** service, how do you know it is foreground vs **background**?

Answer (score 32):

If you use a foreground service, you should call:

[`stopForeground(true);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29)

Just like you start it with `startForeground`.

`stopSelf` is meant to be used for normal services. a foreground service is special... :)

By the way, in case your app should work on older devices, you should check the compatibility code offered [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I'm trying to understand the difference between stopForeground(true) and stopSelf(), but this answer is the only thing I've found talking about the two. More specifically, when I call stopSelf() and stopForeground(true) immediately after, my app seems to leak memory. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: A foreground service has a very low chance of being killed by the OS compared to normal service, and since a foreground service has a notification (to show the user that it's there), you can close it while also removing the notification it holds. "stopSelf" is used for normal services. "stopForeground" is use for foreground services. Here's another link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @androiddeveloper Calling stopForeground(true) does *NOT* mean your service will be stopped. It just means it no longer will be in the foreground and it CAN be stopped from that moment on. But if you want to force stop, you also need to call stopSelf() after stopForeground(true).

Comment: @Tiago Once a foreground service stops being a foreground service, it becomes a normal background service, which means that if it started, you can stop it using "stopSelf". Hope now it's clearer.

Comment: it's better to edit your answer, because it's really sounds like you saying that to stop service which in foreground mode we have to use `stopForeground(true);` when it's switches off foreground mode. so it's just foreground state, it's not some different service which is called foreground one, it's just a state of the same service

Comment: and we don't start service with `startForeground`, service is already started before it, we just enable foreground state with `startForeground`

Comment: This was the reason why my notifications were not getting removed even after calling close(Notification_id).

Comment: from `Service`'s `stopForeground`: `/**
     * Remove this service from foreground state, allowing it to be killed if
     * more memory is needed.  This does not stop the service from running (for that
     * you use {@link #stopSelf()} or related methods), just takes it out of the
     * foreground state.
     *
     * @param flags additional behavior options.
     * @see #startForeground(int, Notification)
     */`

Comment: if you are using a **bind service**, after `stopSelf()` is called, you should also call `unbindService()` otherwise Android will not call  service `onDestory()`

Answer (score 13):

The only way I have found to stop a service with certainty is to use:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

This behavior can be caused by using worker threads that have not finished when the `stopSelf` is called. If you are using worker threads, **be careful** how you employ this - you may leak memory if you don't clean up before executing the line.

Comment: Best Answer. It was because of my Timer thread. I simply called timer.cancel(); before stopSelf();

Comment: it works but it completely kill and stop the App :|

Comment: to me it was because of my WindowManager. mWindowManager.removeView(root) must call before SropSelf();

Comment: I also needed to call stopForeground(true) and (or?) stopSelf(), so my sticky service didn't reappear.  But all together, they finally stopped my app.  Finally.

Answer (score 12):

I met a similar problem.Through my search found that: In other activity's onCreate method I bind the service,but not **unbind** it onDestory method.After fix that,when I call stopSelf then the service's onDestory method is call. I hope it can help you.

At same time,I find base from Android gover document.

> [A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Yes, exactly the issue that I had. A service that is "started and bound both" needs stopSelf() call and all clients to it unbound to be destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and searching I found this thread. My app's problem is that when service calls stopSelf(), the foreground activity that binds the service is still running. Thne stopSelf is called but the service is not destroyed as the foreground activity is still bound. When I leave the activity by pressing back or going to home screen, then the service is destroyed. In short, stopSelf won't work when a foreground activity is bound.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MD, this actually is a response. It is possible the question author wants to do something that is not possible according to Android specifications of services. If that is the case, they need to look at the problem from a different perspective: if I want to keep the foreground activity running while the bound process is destroyed, it is important to unbind the service in the foreground activity. If they directly kill the process with android.os.Process.killProcess, the foreground activity may have an unexpected exception.

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this issue of `selfStop()` that not working too.

The main idea to understand is that the Service WILL NOT stop,

if a running loop is still running (`while(mDoWhile)` for example).

Or any other issue that need to be destroyed / unregistered first.

So to make the `stopSelf()` or `stopService(intent)` works,

implement `onDestroy()` within your service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // Unregistered or disconnect what you need to
    // For example: mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    // Or break the while loop condition
    // mDoWhile = false;

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you both called startService and bindService.you should unbindService frist,otherwish the stopSelf will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem too.

As we all know that `Service` runs on App's `UI Thread`. So, until you've `Thread` that is running in background in your service and you are calling `stopSelf()` then it won't work. For that you have to stop that `Thread` first and then execute `stopSelf()`.

After stoping all background `Thread` from your `Service` `stopSelf()` method will definitely work.

Comment: @Taranfx check documentation of service your self then comment http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way i had to kill the foreground service was to set stopwithtask=true in the manifest

```
    <service
        android:name="my.package.MyForegroundService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:stopWithTask="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of foreground service, it was necessary to remove location updates, unregister sensors, etc.

Add the following code to OnStartCommand when you want to kill the service:

```
    private void selfTerminate() {
    stopForeground(true);
    unregisterBarometer();
    if (locCallBack != null) {
        getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).removeLocationUpdates(locCallBack);
    }
    m_tripState.currentActivity.clock.stopClock();
    stopSelf();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`stopSelf` might not destroy the service if the conditions are not favorable, but you can `stopService` with the application context. But make sure the service doesn't restart before calling `stopService` inside service.

```
stopService(applicationContext, MyService::class.java)
```